# Why is my console spitting out all of this NW_* stuff now? Using React-Native and Xcode

Tags: xcode, console, react-native

Since updating to Xcode 8 (at least I think this is what started it) my console has been filling up with all sorts of network activity stuff like:

[image]

I have no interest in seeing all that, how do I stop this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you googled that prefix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the meantime, simply Edit Scheme -> Run -> Arguments ->Environment Variables -> Click + to add a new one -> Name: OS_ACTIVITY_MODE -> Value: disable.

There is a PR open to fix this too: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/10065

`NSLog` will be suppressed but if you need to log in the native side you can use the logging functions inside `RCTLog.h`, which will still work.

Comment: This worked without hiding the console.log output from React Native at least.

Comment: `NSLog` doesn't work but everything under `RCTLog.h` still works. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This logging is caused by the iOS 10 SDK included in Xcode 8. There is a workaround:

https://twitter.com/rustyshelf/status/775505191160328194

[image]

However, be aware that this hides NSLog output on device.